# Cakephp HABTM issue retrieving multilevel data

Tags: cakephp, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am creating an assessment database and using cakephp for the first time. I have gotten all the data entry and editing sorted but am having trouble retrieving some crucial data from a deep association:

The essence is

Course HABTM Units (table courses_units)

Unit hasMany Artefacts

Artefact hasOne AdminArtefact
Artefact belongsTo an Unit

The AdminArtefact model is used for each years dynamic data for an artefact (due_date, late_date and so on).

My problem is when I want to get all the due dates of artefacts for a particular course (which we need to check for hand in congestion)

If I do a findAll in the Artefacts controller with recursion set to '2' it gets all the data I need...but it overloads the page due to the amount of data returned. So I want to set the conditions for the findAll for the specific fields I need. However I cannot set the course in the query - From my understanding the course data is pulled from a 'separate' query as it appears in the results like this:

```
    [Course] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [course_code] => C0767S
                        [course_name] => BSc (hons) Entertainment Technology
                        [course_local_code] => ET
                        [course_leader] => 6
                        [colour] => 
                        [CoursesUnit] => Array
```

so as part of the query, I cannot set the course equal to a specific one, which I need to do so I can also specify the other data elements I want to pull and not the wealth of other data.

Ive tried loading the Unit model and changing the bind to a belongsTo instead of HABTM to the courses_units table but got the same dataset back again.

Ive tried going 'higher up the chain' to the CourseUnits controller and doing a '$uses' and specified all the relevant tables I want to pull data from  but that didn't get anything useful.

Reading up on HABTM it doesn't automatically pull the data so I looked at joining the tables, but couldn't really see which model to make the join to get it to work.

I need to put this to bed now so hence I am asking the question: What is the most elegant way to get the due dates for all the artefacts for a specific course? (I need the course, the unit, the artefact and the due date...so something from all the tables)

QUERY String I want to use in Artefacts controller:

```
    $data = $this->Artefact->find('all', array(
   'fields' => array('Artefact.reference', 'AdminArtefact.due_date', 'ArtefactUnit.short_code', 'Course.course_code' )));
```

This gives the error:

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Course.course_code' in 'field list'

Thanks in advance!

Kevin

All relevant models:

```
    class Course extends AppModel {     
    public $displayField = 'course_name';
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Unit' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Unit',
            'joinTable' => 'courses_units',
            'foreignKey' => 'course_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'unit_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => 'CoursesUnit'
        )
    );
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'CourseLeader' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'course_leader'

)
    ); 


    class Unit extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'short_code';
    public $hasMany = array( 
    'UnitArtefacts' => array(
    'className' => 'Artefacts',
    'foreignKey' => 'unit_id'
));


    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Course' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Course',
            'joinTable' => 'courses_units',
            'foreignKey' => 'unit_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'course_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => 'CoursesUnit'
        )
    );


    public $belongsTo = array(
    'External' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
    'foreignKey' => 'external_examiner'

),
    'Coordinator' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
    'foreignKey' => 'coordinator'
),
    'UnitLevel' => array(
    'className' => 'Level',
    'foreignKey' => 'level_id'
)
    );


    class Artefact extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'reference';
    public $hasOne = array(
        'AdminArtefact' => array(
            'className' => 'AdminArtefact',
            'foreignKey' => 'artefact_id'

)
    );
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'ArtefactUnit' => array(
    'className' => 'Unit', 
    'foreignKey' => 'unit_id'
)
    );
```

Comment: Setting recursion to 1 (instead of 2) should be sufficient to get all HABTM associations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have tried changing the recursion setting in the Unit and Artefact controller, none of which get what I want (setting it to 1 in Unit doesn't drill deep enough to get AdminArtefact data (and returns the course as a separate array). Setting it as 1 in Artefacts controller loses the course data. Kevin

Answer (score 0):

actually setting

```
'recursive' => 3,
```

should work.

Comment: Hi, I'd tried recursive=3 - it still gets the data in the same form as recursive = '2'. I've added in the query string I want to use in the artefacts controller, but returns the error unknown column.